# Export MsWord doc from outlook to MySQL database

Tags: php, outlook, ms-word, export

Any way to do this using existing applications or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

use a blob data type in mysql

find the path to the file

$doc = file_get_contents( $path  );

//insert into database

you probably want to go directly into the mail account instead of going through outlook

Comment: is it possible to search content for blob data type?

Comment: dont know. would probably be best to store data about the doc in the row